# HUGO URL: triggering the default single page of the layouts when I don't want to

Tags: hugo

My problem is simple from my point of view, but I'm struggling fixing it.

On my Hugo folder, if I resume the structure of my `layouts` and `content` folders, it's like this:

```
layouts
  |--- _default
    |--- baseof.html
    |--- list.html
    |--- single.html
  |--- blog
    |--- list.html
    |--- single.html

content
  |--- blog
    |--- posts
```

The code under `/layouts/blog/list.html` works fine -the design of the list page under the URL on local `http://localhost:1313/blog/` is as I want it to be. **However the code under `/layouts/blog/single.html` isn't working. Instead, I got the implementation of the code of the single page under `/layouts/_default/single.html`.**

The source of this problem might be in the fact that I migrated my blog posts from WordPress with a plugin into Hugo. And the metadata of my blog posts are like this:

```
---
title: ...
author: ...
type: post
date: ...
url: /2020/10/title-of-the-post/
---
```

And the URL of my post on local is: `http://localhost:1313/2020/10/title-of-the-post/`.

What I did is obviously change the url in the metadata of the post to be like this:

```
---
url: /blog/2020/10/title-of-the-post/
---
```

Thus the URL of my post on local is now: `http://localhost:1313/blog/2020/10/title-of-the-post/`.

However, it didn't trigger the single page under `/layouts/blog/single.html` -the code implemented is still the one under `/layouts/_default/single.html`.

I don't have more idea to try. Has someone of you figured out how I could do it ?

Here are my permalinks configuration from the `config.toml` as I guess some of you might ask them:

```
[permalinks]
  post = "/:year/:month/:title/"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution: it was to delete the line `type: post` in the front matter of my posts (or to change it to `type: blog`).